# Equivalence of two XOR logical functions

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations

For practicing I grabbed two logical functions that both represent a XOR Gate. I want to show that these functions are equivalent:

$$
a\overline{b}+\overline{a}b \iff (a+b)(\overline{a}+\overline{b}).
$$

Both functions are taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate).

For now I've come this far:

$$
\begin{align*}
(a+b) (\overline{a}+\overline{b})
&= (a+b) \overline{(ab)} \\ 
& = \overline{(\overline{a}\overline{b})} \space \overline{(ab)} \\ 
& = (\overline{a}\overline{b}) + (ab).  
\end{align*}
$$ 
I have no idea how to go on. I would appreciate if you could state the rules you used in your solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much simpler.

$$
(a+b)(\overline{a}+\overline{b}) = a \overline{a} + b \overline{b} + a \overline{b} + b \overline{a}
$$

Now the first two terms on the RHS are zero since an expression (like $a$) cannot be simultaneously true and false. That's it.

Comment: Didn't expect it to be so simple .. Thanks a lot for you fast response!